# setNavigationBarTint not working in OS 4.2 for iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I just downloaded the new xcode for OS 4.2 and build my old code on it, everything is fine except setNavigationBarTint, I have used a SplitViewController and in that I am using the following line to change the color of the navigation bar :-

```
[self setNavigationBarTint:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

But it does not work, for landscape mode it shows me a black color and for potrait mode it shows a grey color. Please Help, I am trying to submit my app and this is the only thing that is holding me back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you put this code? In what method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe xcode OS 4.2 is still under NDA

Comment: What is Xcode OS 4.2? There's Xcode 4, and theres iOS 4.3(.1). Neither of which are under NDA.

Comment: @Jonathan. November 10th 2010 there was no Xcode 4 and no iOS 4.3. I don't know about the NDA, but it's possible that this answer was correct at the time.

Comment: Sorry didn't check the date, I looked at the wrong list of questions, thinking they were all new.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but here's how to set the tint color of a navigation controller's navigation bar:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```